# Echo attachment download finder filerights

Tags: php, macos, download, attachment, finder

I have the following code:

```
$thumb = file_get_contents( $thumb );
$thumb = str_replace( '#00FF00', '#' . $color, $thumb );

header( 'Pragma: public' ); 
header( 'Expires: 0' ); 
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' ); 
header( 'Cache-Control: private', false );
header( 'Content-Type: image/svg+xml' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="thumb.svg"' );
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );

echo $thumb;
```

But when the file is downloaded the right on mac are like so: me read & write, staff only read, everyone no rights ... is it possible to change it so the downloaded files has right as so: me read & write, staff read & write, everyone read & write?

Comment: You can't control the file privileges on your local files from a remote website. That would be super duper mega insecure. The browser sends the file, your system decides how to store it.

Answer (score 1):

## Notes

It would a major security flaw if downloaded files could automatically have read and write access - especially if that option is decided by the external web server.

Ultimately, it is down to you and your system setup to decide how to store the file. Even if it is possible for your code on an external web server to change the permissions of the file it was downloading, I really wouldn't recommend going down that route.

---

## Solution

I could give you a better approach if you explain more about how you're trying to use these files, I'm assuming it's so they can be editing by an application or Apache on your local computer since you mentioned that you're looking to add write access to everyone.

How I would do this (if on a Mac or Linux based machine) would be to set up a [cron task](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) to change the permission of all files inside of a directory and set it up to repeat every so often. I wouldn't recommend doing this because of the security vulnerabilities, but it would be a solution. See [this example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) on how to setup a Cron job on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hmm ok. The Downloads results in a SVG file and i'am pretty sure that my system not give all downloaded SVGs that rights. My script generates a SVG thumb to use in web projects placed on the localhost. But with that rights the thumbs are not showed in the browser ... so i have to change the right for every downloaded file manually.